# Can I change the icon size in dash?

Tags: 11.04, unity, 11.10, icons, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change icons size inside unity (e.g. on all programs panel)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68763/how-to-change-icons-size-inside-unity-e-g-on-all-programs-panel)

Has anyone found a way to resize the icons in the dash in Natty or Oneiric?

Answer (score 5):

The icon size is hardcoded in 11.04, so this is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the icon size may be changed via number of utilities that are popping up as of late.  The methodology I used was the following:

1. Ensure that the CompizConfig Settings Manager is installed.
2. Open the Ubuntu Control Center and select CompizConfig Settings Manager.
3. In the CompizConfig Settings Manager, enable and select Ubuntu Unity Plugin.
4. In the Ubuntu Unity Plugin, select the experimental tab.
5. Change the dock icon size as you see fit.

EDIT:

Have a misunderstanding as to what the dash is?  I assumed that it was the icon bar on the left of the screen.

Comment: The question is about the Dash icon size - not the Launcher icon size.

Comment: Ahhh..thanks.  I got thinking about it, which in turn prompted my edit before seeing the comment.  Thanks, fossfreedom.