# How to change icons size inside unity (e.g. on all programs panel)

Tags: 11.10, unity, icons

How to change icons size inside unity (e.g. on all programs panel).
I can change launcher icons size but I don't know how to do this "inside" Unity.
I made a screenshot with big icons which I'd like to change.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With "inside" I think you mean the "Dash" (of Unity).

If it's true It's not possible to change the icon size. (i.e. see [this AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40547/can-i-change-the-icon-size-in-dash/40557#40557))

Comment: Curious to see that the question you linked to was marked a duplicate of this one, when it was posted back in May and this was posted last month.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the sizes of those. At least not yet. But considering the text, are you sure you would want to?